# new REngine launch and stop immediately

Tags: java, r, rjava

i want to use JRI to call R from Java.

I m under eclipse to run this in a main class:

```
   Rengine c = new Rengine(new String[] { "--vanilla" }, false, null);
```

first of all i have had a problem to load jri.dll, i have solved my problem in setting this

```
  -Djava.library.path=D:\Users\pmancaux\Desktop\Dev\R\GNU_R\R-3.0.2\library\rJava\jri\
```

i set in environnement execution of eclipse:

```
  PATH D:\Users\pmancaux\Desktop\Dev\R\GNU_R\R-3.0.2\library\rJava\jri\;D:\Users\pmancaux\Desktop\Dev\R\GNU_R\R-3.0.2\bin\;D:\Users\pmancaux\Desktop\Dev\R\GNU_R\R-3.0.2\bin\i386

  R_DOC_DIR D:\Users\pmancaux\Desktop\Dev\R\GNU_R\R-3.0.2\doc
  R_HOME D:\Users\pmancaux\Desktop\Dev\R\GNU_R\R-3.0.2\bin
  R_INCLUDE_DIR D:\Users\pmancaux\Desktop\Dev\R\GNU_R\R-3.0.2\include
  R_SHARE_DIR D:\Users\pmancaux\Desktop\Dev\R\GNU_R\R-3.0.2\share
```

but when i'm doing "new Rengine"... it's start and stop immediatly
see trace in debug mode:

```
  <disconnected>fr.edf.CallRJRI at localhost:50728  
  <terminated, exit value: 2>D:\outils\java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin\javaw.exe (28 mars 2014 10:41:13)
```

What things i doing wrong?

some informations:

i have tape library("rJava") in RGui.exe

```
   Tapez 'q()' pour quitter R.

   > library("rJava") 
   >
```

it seem to don't have any problem, and in java i have JRI.jar and JRIENgine.jar with Created-By: 1.7.0_45 (Oracle Corporation) in manifest file. and in my main method i have

```
               Rengine.DEBUG = 5;
    System.out.println("Starting Rengine..");
    System.out.println("R_HOME =" + System.getenv("R_HOME"));
    System.out.println("java.library.path =" + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));

    Rengine re = new Rengine(new String[] { "--vanilla" }, false, null);
    if (!re.waitForR()) {
        System.out.println("Cannot load R");
        return;
    }
```

but program stop at line new Rengine...
thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you didn't activate R and typed into it:

`library("rJava")` , try this for a start, if this does not work, then please attach your java code, and ill try to find other solutions.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i don t understant your answer. to do library("rJava"), i need REngine instance before to do Rengine.eval("library('rJava')"), but the problem is that rengine stop immediatly before i can do evaluation. Perhaps i miss something or i don t understand your answer. My java code is only à main with the line i post and just after re.eval("source(myfile.R)"); but the programm never go to the second line. I have activate debug and i have a debug from REngine : Starting R... and then nothing, it stop.

Comment: No, activate the `library("rJava")` command in R, not in Java, if this does not work, please add the imports of your java code, and ill try to see whats mising.

Comment: I know that there were some problems with rJava when R version turned into 3, try to use R 2.15 and let me know if that helped

Comment: i can test this but the problem is the version is not fixed by me, it's the client who choose it because R script are already wrote and pass with RScript.exe and they want to use the same version...

Comment: Look at my answer in your newer question, let me know if that helped